# Devise gem current_user is nil before calling sign_out method

Tags: devise, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

Hell all,

I create Rest API is using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.3.0 and Devise gem

After I called method sign_in as below

def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

The value of current_use is not nil. That is signed in user

But when i called the sign_out method as below

```
def destroy
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_out if signed_out
    yield if block_given?
    respond_to_on_destroy
end
```

I debugged into method and set break point at line

```
signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
```

Before I run the line the value of current_user is nil
I wonder about that. I think current_user will be not nil before run the line

Anything was wrong and how can i fix it
Thanks

Comment: Related with my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197019/why-devise-all-signed-out-is-returning-true-when-destroy-is-called